# Match pandas DataFrame to matrix with predefined index and column names

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I am currently struggling with a small problem which I would be very about to be resolved here. I have a predefined matrix which looks like this:

```
    AUS AUT BEL
AUS
AUT
BEL
```

and I have a pandas Dataframe which looks like this:

```
country1 country2 agreements
AUS      AUT      1
AUS      BEL      3
AUT      AUS      3
AUT      BEL      2
BEL      AUS      5
BEL      AUT      3
```

Now I would like to "search" the DataFrame for every index and column name and insert the value from the agreements column. The result should then look like this:

```
    AUS AUT BEL
AUS     1   3
AUT 3       2
BEL 5   3
```

As the DataFrame also contains names / countries which do not match the matrix they should be ignored, or if no value is available NAN should be inserted. Does someone know how to handle, solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.pivot` here.

```
df.pivot(index='country1',values='agreements',columns='country2')

country2  AUS  AUT  BEL
country1
AUS       NaN  1.0  3.0
AUT       3.0  NaN  2.0
BEL       5.0  3.0  NaN
```

Or `df.set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['country1','country2']).unstack()

         agreements
country2        AUS  AUT  BEL
country1
AUS             NaN  1.0  3.0
AUT             3.0  NaN  2.0
BEL             5.0  3.0  NaN
```

or `df.pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index='country1',values='agreements',columns='country2')

country2  AUS  AUT  BEL
country1
AUS       NaN  1.0  3.0
AUT       3.0  NaN  2.0
BEL       5.0  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: Wow, super! Thank you very much for your immediate reply! :)